# Why exit code 141 with grep -q?

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd

Can someone explain why I get exit code 141 from the below?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -o pipefail

zfs list | grep tank
echo a ${PIPESTATUS[@]}

zfs list | grep -q tank
echo b ${PIPESTATUS[@]}

cat /etc/passwd | grep -q root
echo c ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
```

I get

```
...
a 0 0
b 141 0
c 0 0
```

From my understanding exit code 141 is a failure, but the line above gives zero, so it should be success, I would say.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This is because `grep -q` exits immediately with a zero status as soon as a match is found. The `zfs` command is still writing to the pipe, but there is no reader (because `grep` has exited), so it is sent a `SIGPIPE` signal from the kernel and it exits with a status of `141`.

Another common place where you see this behaviour is with `head`. e.g.

```
$ seq 1 10000 | head -1
1

$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
141 0
```

In this case, `head` read the first line and terminated which generated a `SIGPIPE` signal and `seq` exited with `141`.

See "[The Infamous SIGPIPE Signal](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node20.html)" from The Linux Programmer's Guide.

Comment: Conventionally, an exit status *N* greater than 128 indicates the program was terminated by signal *N* - 128. Since `SIGPIPE` is signal 13, 141 - 128 = 13 indicates your program was ended by a `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: Is there a way I can still use `set -o pipefail` and `grep -q`, as I would like to keep it, as I have lots of parsing from SSH.

Comment: @chepner: It's not a matter of convention, it's matter of how shells deal with processes that exit due to a signal. For bash, it's 128 + signal_number, but other shells use other formulas. See this excellent post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99134/9041

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: See [Effective SIGPIPE handling](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/sigpipe_handling.html) for issues with pipefail in bash and alternative to it.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: I have the same issue and it is very annoying.  One idea: Do not use `-q` option with `grep`, but redirect output: `1> /dev/null 2>&1`.  In theory, slightly slower as `grep` will process entire input, but, practically: it works.

Comment: @chepner This just made so much sense to me, after years of never actually going and looking for that answer. Thank you!

Comment: To avoid exit 141 with `head -c` (counting bytes), replace it with `cut -b start_byte-end_byte`.

Comment: An interesting if verbose solution to `SIGPIPE` and `pipefail` is presented here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582850/66344

Comment: If you are just wanting the first line of the result,  then `head -n 1` can be replaced with `sed -n 1p` which doesn't have this failure.

Comment: An alternative solution to a child process exiting with 141 (SIGPIPE) is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72985727/1329892)

Comment: My solution to this is to assign the producer's output to a variable, then `echo` the variable to `grep -q`. It seems that `echo` doesn't exit with error if the pipe is closed.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with `zfs list`, but I guess it complains about its standard output being closed - `grep -q` exits immediately when a match is found, unlike `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to not use a pipe, but use a process substitution:

grep -q tank <(zfs list)

Update: I guess is the same thing, as the process run inside parentheses will also receive sigpipe.

Comment: If looking for a simple solution, I think a very simple one is to assign the output of the producer to a variable, and `echo` that variable to grep. It seems that `echo` doesn't exit with error when `grep -q` closes the pipe.

Comment: @Marcus: It would be worth noting that the output of the producer is no longer streamed when using an intermediate variable. The output of the producer is held all at once in memory in the variable, and `grep`'s processing can start only after the producer completes.

Comment: Actually that's a good answer: `head -1 <(seq 1 10000)` the return code is 0

Answer (score 0):

You can just continue eating the output, e.g.:

```
command | { head -n1; cat >/dev/null; }
```

Comment: Though then wty would you not simply drop the `-q` and the `cat`? `grep whatever >/dev/null`

Comment: You are right, this does not make sense, but for the head -n1 it works.  I will try to edit my answer.