# Ignoring Bash pipefail for error code 141

Tags: python, bash, error-handling, signals, sigpipe

Setting the bash `pipefail` option (via `set -o pipefail`) allows the script to fail if a non-zero error is caught where there is a non-zero error in any step of a pipe.

However, we are running into `SIGPIPE` errors (error code 141), where data is written to a pipe that no longer exists.

Is there a way to set bash to ignore `SIGPIPE` errors, or is there an approach to writing an error handler that will handle all error status codes but, say, 0 and 141?

For instance, in Python, we can add:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

to apply the default behavior to `SIGPIPE` errors: ignoring them (cf. http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2004-06/3823.html).

Is there some similar option available in bash?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `trap` command lets you specify a command to run when encountering a signal. To ignore a signal, pass the empty string:

```
trap '' PIPE
```

Comment: Wouldn't this ignore all non-zero errors and defeat `pipefail`? If so, how would test the error code from the signal that gets raised, so that I can `continue` on 0 and 141?

Comment: This would only ignore `SIGPIPE` errors, leaving other signals unaffected.

Comment: Have I totally misunderstood the question? I assumed it was about ignoring the error code returned by a child process that receives SIGPIPE. This answer is about ignoring SIGPIPE in the current process. So it only helps if the child process is a script that you wrote that you can include this line in. (In which case it's probably wrong -- your child process will write forever if it's consuming infinite input like `/dev/urandom`.)

Comment: There seem to be two opposite questions ("Is there a way to set bash to ignore SIGPIPE errors", which I answered, and "[I]s there an approach to writing an error handler that will handle all error status codes but, say, 0 and 141", which I interpreted as "Handle everything *except* SIGPIPE".)

Comment: this does not work for: `yes | tee >(echo yo)`, for that you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464786/ignoring-bash-pipefail-for-error-code-141#comment60412687_33026977

Comment: Doesn't work for while cond; do echo something; done | head -10
(at least not for GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0))

Answer (score 25):

I handle this on a per-pipeline basis by tacking on an `|| if ...` statement to swallow exit code 141 but generate exit code 1 for any other errors. (The original exit code that caused any non-141 failure is lost, as `$?` was changed by the test after the `if`.)

```
pipe | that | fails || if [[ $? -eq 141 ]]; then true; else exit $?; fi
```

Comment: Assuming `set -e` (`set -o errexit`) is used as well, this can be shortened to `pipe | that | fails || test $? -eq 141` (+ some indispensable comments, of course, that explain magic number).

Comment: Note this doesn't preserve the original exit code from the pipe. Although it appears to, the `else exit $?` will return 1 because of the test command executed by `[[`. An alternative solution that preserves the exit code is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72985727/1329892).

Comment: -1 from me because of the problem mentioned by @SpinUp. [Their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72985727/1329892) is better.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a way that I know of to do this for the whole script. It would be risky in general, since there's no way to know that a child process didn't return 141 for a different reason.

But you can do this on a per-command basis. The `||` operator suppresses any errors returned by the first command, so you can do something like:

```
set -e -o pipefail
(cat /dev/urandom || true) | head -c 10 | base64
echo 'cat exited with SIGPIPE, but we still got here!'
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to set bash to ignore SIGPIPE errors, or is there an approach to writing an error handler that will handle all error status codes but, say, 0 and 141?

An alternative answer to the second question, which ignores the SIGPIPE termination signal from the child process (exit code 141):

```bash
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 || { ec=$?; [ $ec -eq 141 ] && true || (exit $ec); }
```

This uses the `exit` command in a subshell to preserve the original exit code from the command pipe intact, if it's not 141. Thus, it will have the intended effect if `set -e` (`set -o errexit`) is in effect along with `set -o pipefail`.

We can use a function for cleaner code, which allows the use of `return` instead of the trick of putting `exit` in a subshell:

```bash
handle_pipefails() { 
    # ignore exit code 141 from command pipes
    [ $1 -eq 141 ] && return 0
    return $1
}

# then use it or test it as:
yes | head -n 1 || handle_pipefails $?
echo "ec=$?"

# then change the tested code from 141 to e.g. 999 in
# the function, and see that ec was in fact captured as
# 141, unlike the current highest voted answer which 
# exits with code 1.


# An alternative, if you want to test the exit status of all commands in a pipe:
handle_pipefails2() {
    # ignore exit code 141 from more complex command pipes
    # - use with: cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 || handle_pipefails2 "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
    for x in "$@"; do
        (( $x == 141 )) || { (( $x > 0 )) && return $x; }
    done
    return 0
}
```

#### Aside: Question Interpretation

As pointed out in the comments to @chepner's answer, interpreting the first part of the question is more difficult -- one interpretation is, "ignoring error codes from child processes generated by SIGPIPE", and the code above accomplishes that. However, causing Bash to ignore the SIGPIPE *signal* entirely can make a child process write forever, since it never receives a termination signal. E.g.

```bash
(yes | head -n 1; echo $?)
# y
# 141

(trap '' PIPE; yes | head -n 1; echo $?)
# must be terminated with Ctrl-C, as `yes` will write forever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set -o errexit       # Exit on error, do not continue running the script
set -o nounset       # Trying to access a variable that has not been set generates an error
set -o pipefail      # When a pipe fails generate an error

random="$(!(cat /dev/urandom) | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 10)"

echo $random
```

Since we cut off 'cat' we'll get a pipe fail. But by negating the status with the '!' it won't trigger the pipefail detection.

Comment: Note that this will only work if run from a script. It will not work from the commandline