# Why does git log return exit code 141 after exit and how can I avoid it?

Tags: bash, git, macos

I run `git log` command (usually with more options, irrelevant here) and then quit with `q`. However, after I recently installed zsh plugins to display the last command return code, I discovered that this command exits with a non-zero return code.

```
$ git log
$ echo $?
141
```

Why is this happening, is this a sign of any real underlying problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Mureinik The proposed duplicate only explains exit code 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why exit code 141 with grep -q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q), or various others referring to 141 - it's because the pipe gets closed when you `q`uit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that doesn't answer the other related questions here and is useless to me as a git user (and not a git developer)

Comment: It answers the first part, why is it happening, the answers to the other parts are therefore: no; and you don't need to "fix" anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well it sounds like an advice to ignore code warning. May be someone can direct me into git internals then so can I understand how can I patch it there?

Comment: I thought you said you *weren't* a git developer? It's really not clear what, if anything, your problem actually is.

Comment: This is due to your `LESS` config apparently. Here's a blog post from 2016 about this issue : https://www.ingeniousmalarkey.com/2016/07/git-log-exit-code-141.html

Comment: @Aserre thanks, can you post it as answer so I can accept it please?