# bash pipe - if first executable exits, will all downstream executables exit?

Tags: bash, pipe

If I have an arbitrary number of pipe sources and sinks

`exec1 | exec2 | exec3 | ...`

**QUESTION**

1. Then if `execN` exits, will all `execM` downstream (M > N) also exit?
2. What will happen to the ones upstream (M < N)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downstream processes won't necessarily exit. When `execN` exits, it closes the write end of the pipe, which closes the read end of `execN+1`'s standard input. But until `execN+1` tries to *read* from standard input, it won't notice, and even then, it's will simply detect that it has reached the end of the file; it can continue do other things or exit, as it decides.

Upstream, `execN-1` won't notice that `execN` has exited and closed its read end of the pipe until `execN-1` tries to write to its end of the pipe, at which point it will receive a SIGPIPE signal. The default handler for that signal is to exit, but `execN-1` can install its own handler to decide what when and if that situation occurs.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q) for an example of a process exiting and causing a SIGPIPE for the upstream process.