# Why does my shell script fail with exit code 141 when running with busybox ash?

Tags: shell, busybox, ash

I have the following shell script, which works perfectly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -exuo pipefail

event="/dev/input/$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices \
    | sed '1,/Name="SZH usb keyboard"/d' \
    | grep Handlers= \
    | head -n1 \
    | tr '=' ' ' \
    | tr ' ' '\n' \
    | grep -E '^event[0-9]+$' \
    | head -n1)"

echo "Enabling scrolllock for $event ..."
"$(dirname "$0")"/ledToggler.py "$event" scrolllock scrolllock 1 1
```

However, when I replace the `/bin/bash` with `/bin/busybox ash`, it stops working. I get an exit code of 141 and the following output:

```
+ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
+ sed '1,/Name="SZH usb keyboard"/d'
+ grep 'Handlers='
+ head -n1
+ tr ' ' '\n'
+ grep -E '^event[0-9]+$'
+ head -n1
+ tr '=' ' '
+ event=/dev/input/event4
```

Can you tell me what is the problem why it doesn't work with busybox ash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why exit code 141 with grep -q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Not it doesn't. I'm not using `grep -q` at all

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer: _Another common place where you see this behaviour is with `head`._?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Ok but then why does it work with bash but not with busybox? Do they treat the pipe status different?

Comment: Ah looks like GNU grep tolerates being interrupted and busybox grep doesn't

Comment: No, it's because of `pipefail`. It's the `grep Handlers=` command that's exiting with status 141, but since that's not the last command in the pipeline, the only way it matters is if `pipefail` is set.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, but I'm using pipefail with both bash and busybox ash.

Comment: I'm almost sure `pipefail` is unique to the `bash` shell. I can remember when it was added. `ash` is a minimalist shell. Hopefully you can find documentation for `ash` and check whether `pipefail` is part of `ash` or not. I don't think it is. Good luck.

Comment: Your monstrous pipeline looks like it wants to be reimplemented as a simple Awk script, or else scour the world eating brains.

Comment: Or even just `sed '1,/Name="PC Speaker"/d' /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -m1 Handlers=  | tr '= ' ' \n' | grep -m1 -E '^event[0-9]+$'`

Comment: I can confirm that Busybox `ash` supports `pipefail`; if I try to pass in a different option it complains that it is unsupported.