# Bash: surprising behavior of `fc-list | grep -q` with `pipefail`

Tags: bash, grep, sigpipe

I'm losing my sanity here...

Suppose that I want to echo the word `"Sans"`, and then check with `grep` whether it contains the substring `"Sans"` or `"CrazyStuff"`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo Sans | grep -q Sans       && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
echo Sans | grep -q CrazyStuff && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'

set -o pipefail

echo Sans | grep -q Sans       && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
echo Sans | grep -q CrazyStuff && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
```

As expected, `"Sans"` contains `"Sans"`, and does not contain `"CrazyStuff"`, so regardless of the `pipefail` settings,

- the 1st `grep Sans` succeeds
- the 2nd `grep CrazyStuff` fails
- the 3rd `grep Sans` succeeds
- the 4th `grep CrazyStuff` fails

The output is:

```
y
 n
y
 n
```

So far so good.

---

Now, let's replace the constant string `"Sans"` by the output of `fc-list` (it lists installed fonts; You'll probably also have some Sans-Serif font, so it should contain `Sans`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

captured="$(fc-list)"

echo "$captured" | grep -q Sans       && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
echo "$captured" | grep -q CrazyStuff && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'

set -o pipefail

echo "$captured" | grep -q Sans       && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
echo "$captured" | grep -q CrazyStuff && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
```

Since the `$captured` output contains the substring `Sans`, this program behaves exactly as the first one, the output is again:

```
y
 n
y
 n
```

---

Now, the daredevil stunt: instead of `echo`ing the `$captured` output of `fc-list`, we simply invoke `fc-list` four times:

```
#!/bin/bash

fc-list | grep -q Sans       && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
fc-list | grep -q CrazyStuff && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'

set -o pipefail

fc-list | grep -q Sans       && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
fc-list | grep -q CrazyStuff && echo 'y ' || echo ' n'
```

Obviously, it must behave in exactly the same way as the previous two examples, so unsurprisingly, the output is

```
y
 n
 n
 n
```

...wait, *what*?

How can replacing the constant `$captured` output of `fc-list` by actual invocations of `fc-list` change anything at all? It's always just returning exactly the same list of fonts every time.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Even more importantly: how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running `set -o pipefail; fc-list | grep -q Sans; echo $?` shows that the specific exit code it's exiting with 141. You can trigger the same exit code using `fc-list | head`. Exit code 141 can be triggered by piping a command into a second command which does not read all of it. `grep -q` is one such command. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q

Comment: @NickODell Thank you very much for the link! I agree, the underlying cause in this other question does look very similar / exactly the same. But as far as I can tell, the answers for that other question give some explanations for why this happens, but they don't really explain how to avoid this problem. Thanks to your hint, I figured out that apparently, I can do `echo "$(fc-list)" | grep -q ....`, but that looks pretty ugly, and kind-of defeats the purpose of `grep -q`, because the `$(fc-list)` consumes the entire output of `fc-list`. Is there a cleaner way to just force `fc-list` to succeed?

Comment: One idea would be to run fc-list in a subshell, and within that subshell, replace an exit code of 141 with 0. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582850/32067 I don't know if that's any cleaner, though. :)

Comment: @NickODell Oh, yes, this `|| :` is awesome , it also happens to solve the exact problem in my original code. Thank you!
Now I'm wondering: should I try to reformulate the question in such a way that it's better findable, and then add an answer with multiple solution variants? Or should I just delete it? I'd really like to leave something with `grep -q` for reference somewhere... Maybe I'll just wait for the votes, if someone wants to have it answered, I'll answer it, if people just find it silly, I'll delete it.

Comment: Something to be aware about `|| :` is that it swallows other kinds of errors too. e.g. if fc-list is not installed, that will be turned into exit code 0 too. Somewhat defeats the point of pipefail in that case. The third code example in the page I just linked has a more conservative option: `(command; ec=$?; if [ "$ec" -eq 141 ]; then exit 0; else exit "$ec"; fi)`

Comment: Have a look **[How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460402/1765658)**!

Comment: Ok, try this: `mapfile -t fc_list < <(fc-list);for fc in "${fc_list[@]}";do case $fc in *Sans* ) fc_sans+=("$fc");; *CrazyStuff* ) fc_crazy+=("$fc") ;;esac;done;echo ${#fc_crazy[@]} ${#fc_sans[@]}` then `declare -p ${!fc_*}` ! This is not an answer, just an attempt to make you see another way to use [tag:bash].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem (as others have pointed out) is that `grep -q` exits (closing its end of the pipe) before `fc-list` has finished writing to its end of the pipe, so `fc-list` gets a SIGPIPE signal when it tries to continue writing, and exits with an error.

The only reason this doesn't happen with `echo` is that `echo` sends its output faster, so it finishes writing before `grep` has time to find its match and exit. If `echo` were slower, `grep` were quicker, or the output large enough (especially, large enough to fill the pipe's buffer, so `echo` couldn't write everything immediately), you'd see this problem with `echo` as well. This type of timing dependent behavior is known as a ["race condition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), and rather than trying to fix the timing, the correct solution is to write code that isn't timing-dependent.

For pipe failures like this, there are several possible solutions:

1. Don't use `pipefail`. It has an annoying tendency to cause problems like this, especially if you don't fully understand how the programs in a pipe work & interact with each other and the pipe.
2. Avoid using things that don't read their entire input.

   In this case, you could replace `grep -q somepattern` with `grep somepattern >/dev/null`; this gives the same status indication `grep -q` would, but it always reads the entire input (and prints matches, but the redirect discards that).

   Similarly, you could replace `head -n30` with `sed -n "1,30 p"`.
3. Force success status for commands in the middle of the pipe, e.g. replacing `... | fc-list | ...` with `... | (fc-list || true) | ...` (but note that this suppresses *all* errors from `fc-list`, not just pipe failures).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect `grep` will quit as soon as it finds a match. When it quits, it breaks the pipe: `echo` has not finished sending everything. `echo` is terminated abnormally due to a broken pipe signal (`SIGPIPE`), and so fails.

You have set `pipefail`, so that makes the whole pipeline be considered failed.

This is downside of `pipefail`. When you have `command | grep -q pattern`, you usually want that to fail if, and only if, the `pattern` did not occur. If `command` fails, that doesn't matter; if it produced a match before the failure, then that was satisfied.

The POSIX shell, and its predecessors, was designed around this type of use case; Bash introduced `pipefail` for those situations in which you need to check for success from all the pipeline elements. It won't work if any of the second or subsequent pipeline elements abruptly quit, causing the pipe to break for the previous ones.

Comment: It seems that it's the other way around: `echo` is fine with being "cut off", but `fc-list` isn't, and exits with non-zero status when confronted with SIGPIPE.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Ah OK; I latched on to the other example. But the generality is the same.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I wonder if `/bin/echo` would make any difference.