# Why `set -o pipefail` gives different output even though the pipe is not failing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to check if a package is installed in a Ubuntu based system.

Running the following in my terminal returns `true` (exit code 0) since I have those packages:

```bash
dpkg --get-selections | grep -wq <package>
```

Where the <packages> are the following:

- google-chrome
- okular-extra-backends
- scrcpy
- xserver-xorg-video-vmware

When doing this in a script with `set -o pipefail` enabled, for some reason it fails for some of the packages and sometimes don't?

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eEo pipefail

check_package() {
  if ! dpkg --get-selections | grep -wq "$1"; then
    echo false
  else
    echo true
  fi
}

check_package google-chrome
check_package okular-extra-backends
check_package scrcpy
check_package xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

- I tried to remove `-eE` options, but the real culprit is `-o pipefail`
- I test commenting out some of the function calls, when doing so, for some reason sometimes the function echoes `true` an other times echoes `false`. I don't get it. Here's some examples:

---

Example 1

```bash
check_package google-chrome
check_package okular-extra-backends
check_package scrcpy
check_package xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

Result

```
false
false
false
true
```

Sometimes the result is this

```
false
false
true
true
```

---

Example 2

```bash
# check_package google-chrome
check_package okular-extra-backends
check_package scrcpy
check_package xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

Result

```
false
true
true
```

Sometimes the result is this

```
false
false
true
```

What is happening there?

Comment: Although some believe that using `set -euo pipefail` is a "best practice", there are in fact many problems and pitfalls associated with it, and it often leads to subtle problems that can be difficult to debug, even for experienced and knowledgeable shell programmers.  See [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail) and [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Best guess for the cause of the spurious `false` results is that `grep` stops reading input as soon as it finds a match, `dpkg` continues writing and eventually fails to write and gets a `SIGPIPE` error.  `dpgk` then exits with a non-zero exit status and that is the exit status of the pipeline (because of `pipefail`).  See "Bash Pitfalls #60" (referenced in my previous comment) for more information.  You can work around the problem by changing the `grep` invocation so it reads to to the end of its input (and various other ways), but you should consider stopping using `pipefail`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. One question though, I stumble some of the pitfalls of `set -e` as well, mainly when storing the text/option of a whiptail input into a variable. Would you recommend handling manually possible errors with if statements as a replacement of `set -e`?

Comment: Yes, or `cd /etc || { es=$?; echo "cd /etc failed with exit status $es" >&2; exit "$es"; }` or similar. Replace `cd /etc` with whatever command you like.

Comment: Since `errexit` can easily, and even accidentally, be disabled for code where it was previously working, it can't be depended on for dealing with errors, ever.  Code that is truly reliable and robust needs to check explicitly for errors.  `if cmd; then ...` is sometimes the best way to do it.  In the common case where you want to exit the program immediately after detecting an error it's very useful to have a "die" utility function.  (See [BashFAQ/101 - Common utility functions (warn, die)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/101).)  You can then write code like `cmd || die "cmd failed ..."`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why exit code 141 with grep -q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q)